# error in jQuery Post: Could not convert JavaScript argument

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery

I am getting the following error, using jQuery POST method in Firefox.

```
Could not convert JavaScript argument
http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js
Line 4
```

I am using the following code to post information:

```
                        jQuery.post("/webadmin/submitnewarticle", 
                        { 
                            'title': jQuery('#Titletext'), 
                            'submenuname': jQuery('#submenuname'),
                            'status': jQuery('#status')                           
                        },  
                        function(data) {                           
                            alert("Data Loaded: " + data);
                        },"json" );
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `jQuery('#Titletext').val()`, otherwise you'll send a a jQuery object not its value. And the same `.val()` for submenuname and status.

Answer (score 1):

You are using jQuery objects as parameters to your AJAX post. You most likely want to use the value of those text boxes. So your code should become:

```
jQuery.post("/webadmin/submitnewarticle", 
{ 
  'title': jQuery('#Titletext').val(), 
  'submenuname': jQuery('#submenuname').val(),
  'status': jQuery('#status').val()                           
}, function(data) { alert("Data Loaded: " + data); },"json" );
```

Or you can use the `.text()` function. Depends on your needs and the elements used obviously.